# Why If- else condition not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

My if function always return false when variable  have space using

```
'&nbsp;'
```

My string is -

```
var Report = "Tab";
$(Report).text($(Report).text() + '&nbsp;&nbsp;X');

if ($(Report).text() == "Tab  X") {

}
else{

}
```

Comment: I can't see how that function returns anything?

Comment: What is your Tab? Is it a class or ID or an object?

Comment: @Ishan Jain are you using xml or html?

Answer (score 1):

your effectively doing something like this: `$('Tab')` which is not the correct jQuery.

try something like this for starters:

```
var Report = $("#tab");         // cache element with id="tab"
Report.text(Report.text() + '&nbsp;&nbsp;X');

if (Report.text() === "Tab&nbsp;&nbsp;X") {

}
else{

}
```

Comment: I think the real problem is that `&nbsp;` can't be compared to a *real* space-character (`=== "Tab  X") {`).

Comment: @Yoshi that too. Author didn't explain the context fully, so I'm just trying to improve what I see :-)

Answer (score 1):

`&nbsp;` is a HTML entity and you set it with text() which replaces `&` with `&amp;`. Your element ends up with `Tab&nbsp;&nbsp;X`, not with spaces

Comment: @Badaboooooom why not? he might use it with XML, where `Tab` is a node ;)

Comment: uhm .. that is up to the OP to clarify this :D

Comment: You can instead use `.html('&nbsp;')` to convert the entities to text

Answer (score 0):

this is not correct, cause you have no `$('tab')` elements i assume :

```
var Report = "Tab";
 $(Report)
```

your are creating an object from a string !?

also you are comparing htmlspecialchars with nothing so it always will be false your condition.

i suggest this:

```
var Report = "Tab";
Report.text(Report.text()+" X");

if (Report.text() == "Tab  X") {

}
else{

}
```